# Function parameters with duplicate name

Tags: php, function, php-7

I use below codes in php 5.6 and work fine but now I upgrade to php7 and get fatal error.

codes :

```
public function object_all_images($img_type = "thumb", 
$img_type = "jpg")
    {
        $path = "";
        $this->default_image_paths();
        if( $img_type === "thumb" ) 
        {
            $directory = $this->es_thumbDir;
        }
        else
        {
            $directory = $this->es_imgDir;
        }
```

> fatal error : Redefinition of parameter

Comment: The only reason for getting the error, Two same names params get overwritten by other @user1919545

Comment: What is that even supposed to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function must be like this to getting the value of both arguments.

```
public function object_all_images($img_type = "thumb", 
$img_format = "jpg")
{
    $path = "";
    $this->default_image_paths();
    if( $img_type === "thumb" ) 
    {
        $directory = $this->es_thumbDir;
    }
    else
    {
        $directory = $this->es_imgDir;
    }
}
```